# laravel question: ajax click button issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am using ajax for the laravel which increase or decrease quantity will display the 'cart successfully updated'. The first time I click up or down button as image below is not a problem. The message display and then fade out. But when I click again up or down button, the message also display it but doesn't fade out anymore. So may I know how to solve this issue?

[image: My button]

I will share my code right here...

Here is code for the controller file:-

```
public function update(Request $request){
  $qty = $request->newQty;
  $rowId = $request->rowID;
  Cart::update($rowId,$qty);
  echo "Cart updated successfully!";
}
```

And here is the blade file:-
I put the ajax on the blade file as well:

```js
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#CartMsg").hide();
            @foreach($data as $pro)
            $("#upCart{{$pro->id}}").on('change keyup', function(){
                var newQty = $("#upCart{{$pro->id}}").val();
                var rowID = $("#rowID{{$pro->id}}").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'{{url('/cart/update')}}',
                    data:'rowID=' + rowID + '&newQty=' + newQty,
                    type:'get',
                    success:function(response){
                        $("#CartMsg").show();
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#CartMsg").html(response);
                    }
                });
            });
            @endforeach
        });
    </script>
```

and here the div at blade file

```html
<div class="alert alert-info" id="CartMsg"></div>
<div class="cart-qty"> <span>Qty: </span>
    <input type="number" max="10" min="1"
     value="{{$pro->qty}}" class="qty-fill"
     id="upCart{{$pro->id}}">
</div>
```

Almost forgot I forget the important part here is the fade our part.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.alert-info').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the code you use to fade out the message? I see only one `.hide()` method on doc load and no code to fade out. It should not work at all.

Comment: Hi, Sorry my mistake and I already make the update part...please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're mixing both show() and hide() functions with fadeIn() and fadeOut(), and you're using $(document).ready() to handle something that can change multiple times.
It's ok to hide #CartMsg the first time, but then you should do the fadeIn() - fadeOut() inside the "success" section of the ajax call, without showing the #CartMsg again (fadeIn() will do the job).

```
$.ajax({
    url:'{{url('/cart/update')}}',
    data:'rowID=' + rowID + '&newQty=' + newQty,
    type:'get',
    success:function(response){
        //$("#CartMsg").show();                                  // Delete this
        console.log(response);
        $("#CartMsg").html(response);
        $('.alert-info').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();         // And add this (using the class or #CartMsg, depends on your html)
    }
});
```